# Easy PHP, Radioactivity module: Read out a node's current energy?

Tags: nodes, entities

Sorry, this is a super stupid problem but I'm new to PHP and failed at solving it myself.

On my node I have an energy field (Radioactivity module) and a computed field. The computed field is supposed to read out the node's current energy, plug it into a function and return another value.

I have tried all of

float( $entity->field_energy ),

float( $entity->field_energy[0]['value'] ), and

float( array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_energy'))) )

to read out the node's current energy, but everythings gives me an error. When I replace the above with a static number everything works fine.

Can anyone tell me how to read out the energy? I don't even know what data type is used to store the energy.

(I couldn't add a radioactivity tag. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points for doing so.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it is something like

```
float($entity->field_energy['und'][0]['value']);
```

Also, you can do

```
print_r ($entity->field_energy);
```

to see what is contained in object.

also, it may be contained in node object so maybe it is

```
float($node->field_energy['und'][0]['value']);
```

My blind guess but it may help you :)

Comment: Just to avoid future issues with translations or new languages setup use it like this: float($node->field_energy[$node->language][0]['value']);

Comment: redhatlab, excellent remark, i read from default value for simplicity (no language iterations), but your approach is better. Though, one could search through documents and replace all occurances of ['und'] when switching to multilanguage :D

Comment: In addition, you can download/enable the [Devel Module] (http://drupal.org/project/devel) and call `kpr()` on your `$node` or `$entity` object. This is functionally the same as calling `print_r`, but provides a nicer output style.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! This worked perfectly. I used print_r to display the field_energy array and noticed that the values are not stored with integer keys but rather with text keys. It turned out that I have to use `$entity->field_energy['und'][0]['radioactivity_energy']`. For some reason applying float() to this gives me an error though. But if I don't apply float() I can still use the value as a real number.

Comment: try: floatval($entity->field_energy['und'][0]['radioactivity_energy'])